# Unable to Verify JWT Coming from AWS ALB Authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, elixir

I am working with Elixir using the [JOSE package](https://github.com/potatosalad/erlang-jose). I have an [ALB that is using the Authentication Listener rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html), and the data I am getting in the `x-amzn-oidc-data` is supposed to be a JWT containing the user claims. However, while the value is mostly in JWT formatting, it is base64 URL encoded, but **with** padding. As such, JOSE is unable to verify most of the tokens coming in (if a token arrives without padding, JOSE verifies it no problem).

I thought I could fix this by simply stripping the `=` characters from the token in the header, payload and signature, however no combination of that seems to work.

I've used the jwt.io to try and debug the token, and **it complains about the signature becoming invalid if I attempt to strip `=` characters from the payload (only?)**. However, I have tried validating the token using the [Python JOSE library](https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose) and the [Javascript JOSE library](https://github.com/panva/jose), and both are able to. Again though, if I strip the padding characters from the payload, both those libraries tell me the signature verification fails. I have to leave it in for the signature to go through.

Is there a way to massage this token into a format that doesn't include the padding, and could be verified by the Elixir JOSE package? I've tried to reverse-engineer how these libraries are able to decode the tokens while others fail, but I haven't had any luck.

Just for a visual example, this is how the tokens should look

```
eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.tyh-VfuzIxCyGYDlkBA7DfyjrqmSHu6pQ2hoZuFqUSLPNY2N0mpHb3nk5K17HWP_3cYHBw7AhHale5wky6-sVA
```

but the ALB sends me things that look like (note the added padded characters in the payload and signature)

```
eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0==.tyh-VfuzIxCyGYDlkBA7DfyjrqmSHu6pQ2hoZuFqUSLPNY2N0mpHb3nk5K17HWP_3cYHBw7AhHale5wky6-sVA==
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned you have to leave the `=` in for the signature verification to succeed.

The reason JOSE library fails verification is it reconstructs the signing input by decrypting the header + payload, then encrypting them again (This time omitting `=` characters).
https://github.com/potatosalad/erlang-jose/blob/main/src/jws/jose_jws.erl#L378

You can get around this by manually constructing the signing input, and calling the alg library directly, something like this:

```
#data from x-amzn-oidc-data header, key from "https://public-keys.auth.elb." <> aws_region <> ".amazonaws.com/" <> kid

[header, payload, signature] = String.split(data, ".") |> Enum.map(fn part -> :jose_jwa_base64url.decode(part) end)
signing_input = Base.url_encode64(header) <> "." <> Base.url_encode64(payload)
encoded_key = key |> JOSE.JWK.from_pem() |> JOSE.JWK.to_record()
:jose_jws_alg_ecdsa.verify(encoded_key, signing_input, signature, :ES256)
```